# flattening docmute projects with flatex

Tags: archiving, flatex

I wanted to archive a finished project which I managed with `docmute`, but wanted to pack it up with `flatex`; the result was a flat file with a lot of `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`s. How to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the `flatex.c` file flattener on my machine (mingw32), flattened the file into `filename.flt`, and then used gema to remove most of the unnecesary `document` environments with the command `gema -p "\\end\{document\}<U>\\begin\{document\}=" filename.flt filename.lst`. Some checking was still necessary, since there are still two `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` environments (why is this so is left as an exercise for the reader), but the file is clean and lean.